# the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)(asp.net mvc and angular js)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-scope

I am Getting null value in action method when i am pass data from angular js to action method.  i debug and see it hit to the AddCutomer method but data is null(the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). can anyone help me to fix this issue

Admin.js

```
var app = angular.module("adminmdl", [])
app.controller("admincontroller", function ($scope, AdminService) {
    $scope.Action = 'Add';
    GetAllCustomer();
    function GetAllCustomer() {
        var getcust = AdminService.getCustomer();
        getcust.then(function (cust) {
            $scope.customers = cust.data;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error');
        });
    }
    $scope.data = {
        cus_code: '',
        cus_name: ''
    }

    $scope.savecu = function () {

        AdminService.saveCustomerDdetails($scope.cusmodel).then(function (d) {
            $scope.msg = "Insert Successfully";
        });
    }


})
.service('AdminService', function ($http) {

    this.getCustomer = function () {
        return $http.get('GetCustomer');
    }
    this.saveCustomerDdetails = function (customer) {
        return $http.post('/AddCutomer', customer);
    }
})
```

ASP.NET MVC

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddCutomer(Customer customer) {
                te.Customers.Add(customer);
                te.SaveChanges();
                string message = "Success";



            return new JsonResult { Data = message, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };


        }
```

html code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" ng-submit="savecu()"  name="basic_validate" id="basic_validate" novalidate="novalidate">

                                 <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Customer Code</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" ng-model="cusmodel.Customercode" name="required" id="required" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Customer Name</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" ng-model="cusmodel.Customername" name="name" id="name" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="savecu()" class="btn btn-success">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Clear" class="btn btn-success" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <p style="color:green">{{msg}}</p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                @*<div class="form-actions">

                                    </div>*@
                            </form>
```

Comment: Please share the customer.cs definition

Comment: public partial class Customer
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Customer()
        {
            this.projects = new HashSet<project>();
        }
    
        public string cus_code { get; set; }
        public string cus_name { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<project> projects { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @MarcusH i have share the customer.cs its autogenerated one

Comment: did you test my answer?

Comment: yah .. it works i just change the ng-model="cusmodel.Customercode" in to     ng-model="cusmodel.cus_code" thanks @MarcusH

Comment: Great! Please accept/upvote my answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is your autogenerated class

```
public partial class Customer 
{ 
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.??Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")] 
    public Customer() 
    { 
        this.projects = new HashSet<project>(); 
    } 
    public string cus_code { get; set; } 
    public string cus_name { get; set; } 
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.??Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")] 
    public virtual ICollection<project> projects { get; set; } 
}
```

The first issue I see is that your client object that you post to the server doesn't match the class definition.
Change the ng-models to `cusmodel.cus_code` and `cusmodel.cus_name`

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Customer Code</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ng-model="cusmodel.cus_code" name="required" id="required" >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Customer Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ng-model="cusmodel.cus_name" name="name" id="name" >
    </div>
</div>
```

The names in the scope model need to match the class specification else the json deserializer don't know what to do here.
Try to make a new post when these changes are added and see if the values of the `cus_code` and `cus_name` is populated.

**If** this doesn't work I would use a data transfer object to handle the communication with the client instead. Populating autogenerated classes from EF(or what orm you use) from the client can be a mess.
Add this class:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{
    public string cus_code { get; set; }
    public string cus_name { get; set; }
}
```

And use it in the controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddCutomer(CustomerDTO customer) {
    var cust = new Customer{ cus_code = customer.cus_code, cus_name = customer.cus_name };
    te.Customers.Add(cust);
    te.SaveChanges();
    string message = "Success";
    return new JsonResult { Data = message, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```